# Emberjs: how to reach the action of a parentView within an itemsViewClass

Tags: ember.js

Cannot get my head around the following problem. I got a `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined` whatever I try. I think it must be the controllerBinding in the itemsViewClass, however I think it is defined correctly.

In the code below there are two `showMenu` actions. The first one works, but the last one in the itemsViewClass does not.

Please take a look at my code below (I show only the relevant code):

```
//views/menu.js
import Ember from "ember";
var MenuitemsView = Ember.View.extend({
    template: Ember.Handlebars.compile('<div{{action "showMenu" target="view"}}>this works already</div>\
        much more code here'),
    contentBinding: 'content',

    itemsView: Ember.CollectionView.extend({
        contentBinding: 'parentView.subCategories',
        itemViewClass: Ember.View.extend({
            controllerBinding: 'view.parentView.controller', // tried to add controllerBinding but did not help
            // this is where the question is all about
            template: Ember.Handlebars.compile('<div {{action "showMenu" target="parentView"}}>dummy</div>')
        }),
        actions: {
            showMenu: function(){
                // dummy for testing
                console.log('showmenu itemsView');
            }
        }
    }),

    actions: {
        showMenu: function() {
            console.log('showMenu parentView!'); // how to reach this action?
        }
    }
});

export default MenuitemsView;
```

I have tested with `{{action "showMenu" target="view"}}` and without a target. It seems not to help.

Do someone have a clue why the second showMenu action cannot be reached?

Comment: Your syntax is a little confusing.  Are your action functions deliberately inside your View?  If so, that would be the first thing causing an issue.

Comment: @Fishbowl, thanks for your comment. Yes I have place the actions deliberately inside my view. I works for the first `{{action "showMenu"}}` call though. Only the second won't work, whatever I try. But what do you think is the best way to call an action from a view?

Comment: I'm adding a full response below, as it's a bit more explaination than will fit in a comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so this is by no means the *only* way to do logic separation in Ember, but it's the method I use, and seems to be the method generally used in the examples across the web.

The idea is to think of events and actions as separate logic pools, where an event is some manipulation of the DOM itself, and an action is a translatable function that modifies the underlying logic of the application in some way.

Therefore, the flow would look something like this:

`Template -> (User Clicks) -> View[click event] -> (sends action to) -> Controller[handleLogic]`

The views and the controllers are only loosely connected (which is why you can't directly access views from controllers), so you would need to bind a controller to a view so that you could access it to perform an action.

I have a jsfiddle which gives you an idea of how to use nested views/controllers in this way:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fishbowl/HE48J/18/)

If you look at the Javascript for that fiddle, it shows that if you use the view/controller separation, you can specifically target controllers to use their actions, utilising the `needs` keyword within the controller.  This is demonstrated in the LevelTwoEntryController in the fiddle.

At an overview level, what should happen if your bindings are correct, is that you perform an action on the template (either by using a click event handler in the view, or using an `{{action}}` helper in the template itself, which sends the action to the controller for *that template*.  Which controller that is will depend on how your bindings and routing are set up (i've seen it where I've created a view with a template inside a containerView, but the controller is for the containerView itself, not the child view).  If the action is not found within that controller, it will then bubble up to the router itself (***not the parent controller***), and the router is given a chance to handle the action.  If you need to hit a controller action at a different level (such as a parent controller or sibling), you use the `needs` keyword within the controller (see the fiddle).

I hope i've explained this in an understandable way.  The view/controller logic separation and loose coupling confused me for a long time in Ember.  What this explaination doesn't do, is explain why you are able to use action handlers in your view, as I didn't even know that was possible :(

Comment: Wow that clarifies a whole lot for me! However one question left: to hand over all actions I should have a `controllerBinding` on my view right? Like this: `{{view "menu" categoryId="21" contentBinding="controllers.categories" controllerBinding="controllers.menu"}}`. I need to have a singleton controller because every menu has a submenu with a different state.

Comment: Depends.  If you have different controllers with different functions for each submenu, then you just need to have the correct naming convention and the linking happens automatically (i.e. SubMenuView would use SubMenuController), otherwise, yes you would have to do controllerBinding.  Unfortunately that has been known to be buggy depending on how you're doing it.

Comment: Thank you, however I have a bunch of questions about it. Maybe I can hire you for a hour or two?

Comment: I am by no means an expert, but feel free to drop me an email (go via my website linked in my profile, there's a link there)